# jQuery for loop on ajax call and wait until all is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, loops

He I have a problem
I need to send multiple AJAX calls to the same URL but with different data.
I need to send it in chunks and wait until all requests are done before my _.each function.

i did a simple chunk function that slice my array and slip it to groups.

my code:

```
 ---- js ----

batch = [0,1,2,3,4,5,....] // big array
var xhr =  chunk(batch, 20);
     for (i=0; i < xhr.length ; i++ ) { 
     //loop number of time of xhr.length
     ajax.call("/", "POST", {batch: xhr[i]}).done(function(resp){
                   arrayResp.push(resp);
                });
     }

/// after all ajax calls and arrayResp is done 
exectue 
_.each(arrayResp, function (element) {
//do somting
});

  ----- /js -----
```

i need to get in the end a full array that holds all my resp data

I can't do $.when() because I can't name the function
And I didn't figure out how to use the $.Deferred() in this function
Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var res = [];
    // this may not be needed
    var arrayResp = [];

    batch = [0,1,2,3,4,5,....] // big array
    var xhr =  chunk(batch, 20);
         for (i=0; i < xhr.length ; i++ ) { 
           //loop number of time of xhr.length
           // push `ajax` jQuery promise to `res`
           res.push(
             ajax.call("/", "POST", {batch: xhr[i]})
             // this may not be needed,
             // see `arguments` at `.then`
             .done(function(resp){
                       arrayResp.push(resp);
             })
           );
         }
// when all `xhr` complete , 
// process array of `xhr` jQuery promises 
$.when.apply($, res)
.then(function() {
  // do stuff with `arrayResp``
  console.log(arrayResp, arguments);
});
```